# NBA Regression Inaccurate Data Retrieval

Tags: datatables, header, regression

I created a code with he help of AI to help predict NBA outcomes. Here's part of my code that calculates the differences:

```
def calculate_differences(team_data, opponent_data):
    return (
        team_data['ORtg'].values[0] - opponent_data['ORtg'].values[0],
        team_data['DRtg'].values[0] - opponent_data['DRtg'].values[0],
        team_data['SOS'].values[0] - opponent_data['SOS'].values[0],
        team_data['SRS'].values[0] - opponent_data['SRS'].values[0],
        team_data['TS%'].values[0] - opponent_data['TS%'].values[0],
        team_data['TOV%'].values[0] - opponent_data['TOV%'].values[0],
        team_data['Age'].values[0] - opponent_data['Age'].values[0],
        team_data['ORB%'].values[0] - opponent_data['ORB%'].values[0],
        team_data['W'].values[0] - opponent_data['W'].values[0],
        team_data['3PAr'].values[0] - opponent_data['3PAr'].values[0],
        team_data['Pace'].values[0] - opponent_data['Pace'].values[0]

    )
```

The differences between each team is calculated and put in my regression equation:

```
def predict_outcome(ortg_difference, drtg_difference, sos_difference, srs_difference, ts_difference, tov_difference, threepar_difference, pace_difference, 
                    intercept_win, coef_ortg_difference, coef_drtg_difference, coef_sos_difference, coef_srs_difference,
                    coef_ts_difference_win, coef_tov_difference_win, coef_threepar_difference_win, coef_pace_difference_win):
    log_odds = (
        intercept_win +
        coef_ortg_difference_win * ortg_difference +
        coef_drtg_difference_win * drtg_difference +
        coef_sos_difference_win * sos_difference +
        coef_srs_difference_win * srs_difference +
        coef_ts_difference_win * ts_difference +
        coef_pace_difference_win * pace_difference +
        coef_tov_difference_win * tov_difference +
        coef_threepar_difference_win * threepar_difference
    )

    probability_win = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-log_odds))
    return probability_win, log_odds
```

This is part of my

```
def(main):

    ortg_diff, drtg_diff, sos_diff, srs_diff, ts_diff, pace_diff, tov_diff, threepar_diff, age_diff, orb_diff, win_diff = calculate_differences(team_data, opponent_data)


    probability_win_main_first, log_odds_win_main_first = predict_outcome(
        ortg_diff, drtg_diff, sos_diff, srs_diff, ts_diff, pace_diff, tov_diff, threepar_diff,
        intercept_win, coef_ortg_difference_win, coef_drtg_difference_win, coef_sos_difference_win,
        coef_srs_difference_win, coef_ts_difference_win, coef_pace_difference_win, coef_tov_difference_win, coef_threepar_difference_win
    )
```

These are different parts of my code that all have to do with predicting just the outcome and the probability.

My main issue was I was getting really crazy numbers and probabilities:

```
Team: Magic
Opponent: Heat
\-Magic BEATS Heat: 100.00%
Odds for Win: **840568.56** (higher = better)
Regression for Win: 13.64
Win (1) Distance: -12.64
Predicted Margin: 1.02
Halftime Lead Probability: 54.53%

Team: Heat
Opponent: Magic
\-Heat BEATS Magic: 0.00%
Odds for Win: **0.00** (higher = better)
Regression for Win: -13.64
Win (1) Distance: 14.64
Predicted Margin: -1.02
Halftime Lead Probability: 45.68%
```

I added some code to help debug and point out any issues. I wanted code to tell me what values the code used to get its calculations. This is what was returned:

```
WinLoss Regression Formula:
Log Odds (Win) = 1.0330e-17 + -2.2130 * ORtg Difference + 2.0735 * DRtg Difference + -2.0870 * SOS Difference + 2.1643 * SRS Difference + 27.2186 * TS% Difference + -0.1440 * Pace Difference + -0.1907 * TOV% Difference + 4.0731 * 3PAr Difference

Differences:
ORtg Difference: -2.2000
DRtg Difference: -3.0000
SOS Difference: 0.9100
SRS Difference: 1.7900
TS% Difference: -0.0120
Pace Difference: 1.1000
TOV% Difference: -4.6000
3PAr Difference: 3.1000


2.0999999999999943
```

the number at the very bottom represents the actual Pace difference between teams. this is what I used to see that:

```
 # Print Differences
        print("\nDifferences:")
        print(f"ORtg Difference: {ortg_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"DRtg Difference: {drtg_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"SOS Difference: {sos_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"SRS Difference: {srs_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"TS% Difference: {ts_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"Pace Difference: {pace_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"TOV% Difference: {tov_diff:.4f}")
        print(f"3PAr Difference: {threepar_diff:.4f}")
        
        print(team_data['Pace'].values[0] - opponent_data['Pace'].values[0])
```

As you can see the correct Pace Difference is 2.09. However the  pace_diff used in the formula is 1.1

What could have gone wrong between the calculation of the Pace difference to def(main) where pace_diff becomes a completely different value?

Comment: Please add a *language* tag.